# Array List count to users

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I wrote a class that does different things. I am trying to user a loop to count the number of users in an array list. Basically the class is taking information and adding that info regarding students. One of the things being entered is the number of credits being taken by students. Let say I entered 5 students into my array list. two students are taking 5 credits 2 students are taking 6 credits and the last student is taking 9 credits. I created some code in the class, let say that the user wants to know how many students in the array are taking 6 credits. So I created a segment that lets the user enter that number and the class would look in the array and return how many students are taking that number, but its not working. I dont know if this makes sense

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number of credits:\n");
inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
int credits = Integer.parseInt(inputInfo);

int count = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i)
{
  count++;
}   


System.out.println("The number of students who are taking " + credits
                               + " credits is: " + count);

break;
```

Comment: This code does nothing except compute `studentList.size()`.

Comment: Exactly this piece of code does nothing other then printing out what you entered along with the size of the list itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array List and counting loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899991/array-list-and-counting-loops)

Comment: @user714965 They are the same question, by the same user, but this one was posted first XD

Answer (score 1):

For each student, you have to check whether he has the same amount of credits that you are looking for.

Replace your `for` loop by:

```
/* If your list contains an array of Student objects */
for(Student student : studentList) {
   if (student.getCredits() == credits) {
       count++;
   }
}
```

---

```
/* If you don't use objects */
for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
   if(studentList[i].credits == credits) {
       count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never actually check if they are taking the right number of credits. Put this in your loop:

```
if(studentList[i].credits == credits) {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the student's credits match the required value. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i)
{
  if(studentList[i].credits == credits)
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the student at a certain index has the number of credits you are looking for or not. If it has just increment the counter, otherwise keep looping through the list till the end of the list.

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number of credits:\n");
inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
int ncredits = Integer.parseInt(inputInfo);
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++){
    // if the student at this index has ncredits
    // then

    count++;
}   


System.out.println("The number of students who are taking " + credits
                           + " credits is: " + count);
```