# Array List and counting loops

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I wrote a class that does different things. I am trying to user a loop to count the number of users in an array list. Basically the class is taking information and adding that info regarding students. One of the things being entered is the number of credits being taken by students. Let say I entered 5 students into my array list. two students are taking 5 credits 2 students are taking 6 credits and the last student is taking 9 credits. I created some code in the class, let say that the user wants to know how many students in the array are taking 6 credits. So I created a segment that lets the user enter that number and the class would look in the array and return how many students are taking that number, but its not working. I dont know if this makes sense

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a number of credits:\n");
      inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
   int credits = Integer.parseInt(inputInfo);

     int count = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i)
      {
        count++;
       }   


      System.out.println("The number of students who are taking " + credits
                           + " credits is: " + count);

       break;
```

Comment: Please show more code, esp. how the credits are stored - show your class.

Comment: user2340248 why are you posting this question again? The other one was already answered..

Comment: And why did your code formatting get so much worse between that question and this one?

Answer (score 2):

You're looping through the array but you're not doing nothing on it.
You should take each student from the list and check the proposed condition. I'm not putting the code because I think that is your homework part.

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
   Student student = studentList.get(i);
   if (student.getCredits() == credits) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

better use this way to iterate your list:

```
for (Student student : studentList) {
   if (student.getCredits() == credits) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: At over 11K rep., don't you think it might be time to edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714965/user714965) to change the name to something that looks less like the number they stamp on the clothes of prisoners?  The name does not have to be your own, but it just looks ..tacky as `user71....`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes you are probably right. I will think about this and maybe it even raises my credibility ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you have ; ++i in your loop, but don't you want i++?

Also you want to check if the credits for a particular student is equal to the credit value inputed by the user.  assuming credits for individual students are stored in the arrayList creditList:

```
 int count =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
        count = (creditList.get(i)== credits)?count+1:count;
```

Comment: He/She need to count the number of students with a certain quantity of credits.

Comment: Yes, `i++` is more common, but `i++` and `++i` are equivalent at the end of a for-loop. The update statement is executed on its own, and *then* the conditional is rechecked, so as long as `i` gets incremented, it doesn't matter whether it happened before or after the result was returned (since the return value was never collected).

Comment: It would make a difference if you had a loop like `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= j; j = ++i) {...}`. This is an infinite loop, whereas if you used `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= j; j = i++) {...}` it only goes through one iteration.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Thanks for the clarification - that makes sense now that I think about it.  Good stuff

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `credits` against something. Right now, you're just incrementing `count` every time through the loop (which always results in `count == studentList.size()`). What you want is to check whether each student is taking that number of credits:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i) {
    if (studentLost.get(i).getNumberOfCredits() == credits) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

The above example assumes you've got some kind of `Student` class with a `getNumberOfCredits()` method to return the number of credits that student is taking. Without seeing your code, that's my best guess.

Also note that since the position of each student within the list isn't important, you can use an [enhanced for-loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) to make your code a little cleaner:

```
for (Student student : studentList) {
    if (student.getNumberOfCredits() == credits) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a more functional approach with predicates and filters.

```java
public class StudentCredit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(new Student(5), new Student(5),
                new Student(6), new Student(6), new Student(9));
        final int six = 6;
        Predicate<Student> hasSixCredits = new Predicate<Student>() {
            public boolean isTrue(Student object) {
                return object.getCredit() == six;
            }
        };
        List<Student> studentsWithSix = Filter.filter(students, hasSixCredits);
        System.out.println("Number of students with " + six + " credits is: "
                + studentsWithSix.size());

        Filter<Student> filter = new Filter<Student>();
        List<Student> result = filter.apply(students);
        System.out.println("Apply empty filter. #students: " + result.size());

        List<Student> otherResult = filter.setPredicate(hasSixCredits).apply(
                students);
        System.out.println("Apply 6-credits filter. #students: " + otherResult.size());
    }
}

class Student {
    private final int credit;

    public Student(int credit) {
        this.credit = credit;
    }

    public int getCredit() {
        return credit;
    }
}

interface Predicate<T> {
    /* tautology - always true */
    public static final Predicate<Object> ALWAYS_TRUE = new Predicate<Object>() {
        public boolean isTrue(Object object) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    /* contradiction - always false */
    public static final Predicate<Object> ALWAYS_FALSE = new Predicate<Object>() {
        public boolean isTrue(Object object) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    public boolean isTrue(T object);
}

final class Filter<T> {
    private Predicate<? super T> predicate = Predicate.ALWAYS_TRUE;

    public Filter() {
    }

    public Filter<T> setPredicate(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        return this;
    }

    public List<T> apply(List<T> list) {
        List<T> filtered = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T element : list)
            if (predicate.isTrue(element))
                filtered.add(element);
        return filtered;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> filter(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return new Filter<T>().setPredicate(predicate).apply(list);
    }
}
```

With this approach you can also create other predicates and you doesn't need to do the counting. Your only concern is the logic of the predicate.

Comment: A homework answer for the great world of Enterprise? =P

Comment: haha :D Wanted to do sth. different.